# Facebook's API and the App Store's User Generated Content policy

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, app-store, testflight

I'm working on an app that displays Facebook posts and comments via the iOS SDK. I uploaded a beta to TestFlight only for it to be rejected:

> 14.3: Apps that display user generated content must include a method for filtering objectionable material, a mechanism for users to flag
>   offensive content, and the ability to block abusive users from the
>   service .
>
> It is necessary that you put all of the following precautions in
>   place:
>
> - Require that users agree to terms (EULA) and these terms must make it clear that there is no tolerance for objectionable content
> - Use moderators to flag and remove inappropriate content and offensive users
> - Users need a mechanism to flag objectionable content and report users generating this content
> - Developer must act on objectionable content reports within 24 hours by removing the content and ejecting the user who provided the
>     offending content
> - Developer needs a method for ejecting users who violate the terms of the EULA

This seems a little onerous, and in some cases downright impossible (I can't really 'eject' users from Facebook). Is every app using the Facebook API truly expected to implement these features? Is so, **does the SDK provide any methods to achieve this**? Or is this an over-zealous reviewer and I should appeal?

Comment: _“I can't really 'eject' users from Facebook”_ – but you _can_ prevent them from using your app any more, and filter out any content created by them that you pull from Facebook.

Comment: my app doesn't have any server component so I can't really blacklist anyone from using the app. But yes, I can allow users to block others' posts client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a bit late to reply this but maybe someone else can find this useful. 
I created an app that pulls and shows tweets based on a keyword search and a sentiment analysis component. Obviously some tweets can contain offensive language. My app has an option to delete or dismiss any tweet. By this I mean not be seen within my app, the tweet can't be removed from Twitter. This was enough for my app to be accepted for beta testing through TestFlight. Now notice that for being accepted on the app store they might be more strict so I need to cross my fingers.
Hope this helps

Comment: Yes this about matches my experience - some nominal effort on the client side.

Comment: Did you also pass the app store review afterwards? I am still in beta.

Comment: I did. Thought I might have also bumped into a more permissive reviewer.